# Bad value true for attribute autoplay on element video

Tags: html

So I am using HTML 5 to play video in the background. The issue is that I am using the old way of HTML 5 does anyone know the new HTML5 way to play the video in the background however it should also display a image if on mobile.

Here is my solution:

```html
 <div class="background-wrap">
<video poster="css/style.css" id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
      <source src="video/husky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="video/husky.webm" type="video/webm">
      Video not supported
   </video>
</div>
</div>
```

When ever I run the validation I get the following:

Error: Bad value true for attribute autoplay on element video.
From line 36, column 1; to line 36, column 106
nd-wrap">↩↩

My website:
https://edgaraxe.net/teamhusky/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `true` value for the `autoplay` attribute.

```
<video poster="css/style.css" id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop="loop" muted="muted">
      <source src="video/husky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="video/husky.webm" type="video/webm">
      Video not supported
 </video>
```

This acts like the `controls` or `required` attributes.  `required` or `required="required"` are both valid.

I have validated this against the W3C for you:

[image]